# compare TCHAR* and values from a TCHAR* []

Tags: c++, arrays, unicode

I'm having trouble using TCHAR and _T() correctly in C++. something weird is happening with the difference in wide/narrow character representation

I have a response from a server that is just a string represented as a TCHAR*

```
TCHAR * response = getTheResponseFromTheServer();
```

I want to compare this value to an array of possible values, to see if any of them match. I have defined the array as such:

```
TCHAR * knownCodes[] = {_T("appleCode"), _T("pearCode"), _T("grapeCode")};
```

but for some reason,  when i compare a value from the array and the response using tcsmpr, they are not equal

```
_tcscmp(response, KnownProductCodes[i]) //this never returns 0; they are not equal even when i know they are
```

When I print them both out with %s, only the known code from the array is displayed correctly, the response code is jumbled with ????'s

When I print them both with %hs, the response code is displayed correctly, and only the 1st letter of the knownCodes[i] is displayed at all. (a, p, or g)

When printed correctly, they both print the same string "appleCode"

Obviously i have some sort of misinformation on the difference between char and wchar, or how to use arrays.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You really should show what `getTheResponseFromTheServer` function does.  Maybe you're returning a pointer to a buffer that is stored on the stack.

Comment: I actually don't have that code. I'm wondering why you think it is relevant? I know that the response has the correct string in it. i can print it out and it's correct. its just that the character formatting is different on the known code vs the response.

Comment: In that case, are you absolutely sure it returns a `wchar_t*`?  The problem with `TCHAR` is that it's a macro which changes the size of the type, depending on options specified at compile time.  If you're linking to some library, it might be that the library's `TCHAR` is actually `char`, while yours is compiled as `wchar_t`.  You should turn on _all_ compiler warnings and check whether there is a warning generated for `TCHAR * response = getTheResponseFromTheServer();`

Comment: Alternatively you could try this (if your compiler supports C++11 or later): `auto response = getTheResponseFromTheServer(); static_assert( sizeof(*response) == sizeof(TCHAR), "TCHAR strikes again" );`

Comment: thanks you for helping me out here. I'll try and figure out if there are any warnings. let's just assume that the response is somehow actually returned as a char* instead of a wchar_t*. shouldn't a simple conversion be in order?

Comment: Yes, in that case a conversion would be required because the basic character widths are different.  You can use functions from the standard library provided by `<codecvt>`, or the WinAPI functions (from memory, `MultiByteToWideChar`).

Comment: Alright. I'm working on a fix. thanks for your help again in the meantime. I'll update this post when i find a solution

Comment: have you tried the debugger?

Comment: unfortunatley this is all happening inside of an environment where debugging is not possible.

Comment: function returning `char *` or `wchar_t *` is suspicious; where is the memory allocated that it points to?  The fact that you could output the string is no guarantee that it is allocated properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this quick function I wrote in C to debug your issue. Note: it's not perfect, probably has bugs, but should hopefully help you figure out what's wrong. It assumes that first character (if it's wchar_t), doesn't use the second byte, which happenns if it's a letter from 'a' => 'z', '0' => '9'
You can use it like:

```
quick_debugger((wchar_t*)response, (wchar_t*)knownCodes[i]);
```

and

```
int quick_debugger(wchar_t *a, wchar_t *b)
{
    int w = 1;
    size_t a_len, b_len;

    if (((char*)a)[1] != 0)
    {
        if (((char*)b)[1] == 0)
        {
            wprintf(L"error: response is char*, but knownCodes is wchar_t*\n");
            return 1;
        }

        printf("comparing char* strings (%s, %s)\n", (char*)a, (char*)b);
        a_len = strlen((char*)a), b_len = strlen((char*)b);
    }
    else if (((char*)b)[1] != 0)
    {
        wprintf(L"error: response is wchar_t*, but knownCodes is char*\n");
        return 2;
    }
    else
    {
        wprintf(L"comparing wchar_t* strings (%s, %s)\n", a, b);
        a_len = wcslen(a), b_len = wcslen(b);
        w = 2;      
    }

    if (a_len != b_len)
    {
        wprintf(L"length is not the same (%d, %d)", a_len, b_len);
        return 3;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < (a_len * w); i++)
    {
        if (((char*)a)[i] != ((char*)b)[i])
        {
            printf("characters at pos %d dont match: %c != %c", (i / w), ((char*)a)[i], ((char*)b)[i]); 
            return 4;
        }
    }

    wprintf(L"quick_debugger: strings match\n");
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: Thank you. I will test this 1st thing tomorrow morning. I'm going to have to modify where the errors are printed, but i should be able to use it.

Comment: I have actually gotten it to work. This function was helpful as it helped me look at all the possibilities of which format the data could be in.

so basically: the server is apparently always returning narrow characters. so i just uses _snprintf_s to write into allocated char* pointers for the known codes (in an array), and then cast the TCHAR* response to char* when i compare, now using strcmp()